# Problems using iterrows() with Pandas DF after slice/reset index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several thousand rows I read in from a CSV file, which contain data that is used in calculating different outputs. I read in this CSV file and store the input in a Pandas dataframe.  I then use `itterrows()` to loop through the dataframe.  Sometimes my code fails, at which point I wish to read in the original file, but pick up the process at the row after failure.  So when this happens, have my code setup so that I un-comment two lines and slice the original dataframe down to size before entering the `itterrows()` for loop:

```
# slicing it and re-indexing when a restart is needed
df_slice = df.iloc[1292:,]
for index,row in df_slice.iterrows():
```

However, if I slice the original dataframe as seen above, the index value in the `itterrows()' loop starts at 1292, and so skips 1292 places from the top of the smaller, sliced dataframe.  How can I get it to start at 0/1?

I tried resetting the index:

```
# slicing it and re-indexing when a restart is needed
df_slice = df.iloc[1292:,]
df_slice.reset_index()

for index,row in df_slice.iterrows():
```

But that doesn't change a thing - the index in the `for index,row in df_slice.iterrows():` still is stuck at 1292 and so jumps 1292 spots down the sliced index.

So, how can I either direct `iterrows()` to a certain starting row (on the original index) or properly slice and reset the index of the smaller dataframe to be able to start at the new 'top' row and move down.

Answer (score 5):

You need to slice your DataFrame using `.ix` rather than `.iloc` as follows:

```
df_slice = df.ix[1292:]
```

I just had a similar problem and my confusion came from the fact that there are two different ways of slicing DataFrames in Pandas. By label (`.ix`) and by integer position (`.iloc`). `df.itterows()` returns a label based index, so to pick up where you left off you need to use `.ix`

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem here:
df_slice.reset_index() doesn't reset the index on df_slice but on a copy of it. Use drop so the old index will not appear as column in df_slice.

```
df_slice.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
```